# WiFi and Bluetooth connection problems in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth, airplane-mode

I am not able to connect to any WiFi network instead of the one connected to during installation. In the *select network* menu, it does not detect any wireless network.

Also, **Bluetooth** and **airplane** mode turn on automatically sometimes. I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 on HP pavilion.

I have used Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 before but never encountered such problems.